# Android DatePicker Button not working

Tags: android

Ok so i have this app i'm working on... It has a left menu slide-out using ABS and the sliding menu lib. Here's my fragment that is launched once the menu item is selected. This fragment is suppose to have a text field to display the date you select and a button to select a date. Any idea's on what i'm doing wrong that SelectDateFragment is erroring?

Here's the XML layout:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateselected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickdate"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateselected"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateselected"
        android:contentDescription="@string/selectdate"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:onClick="selectDate"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_datepicker" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the java class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class DatePicker extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstaceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_charting, container, false);
    }

    EditText mEdit;
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }


    public void selectDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        mEdit = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.dateselected);
        mEdit.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
    }

    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            populateSetDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:
I'm trying to follow http://javapapers.com/android/android-datepicker/

The error i'm getting is the fragment inner class should be static. I don't understand enough about this topic, and from reading more i still do not, to understand why his works and mine does not.

Comment: what exactly it is erroring?

Comment: public class SelectDateFragment

Comment: you can set it to static if arent gonna change it lateron anyways. static and final, check that on some java-source. you will find this more often!

Comment: it can be changed because every time they chick the button it will repopulate that text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
shipdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(999);

        }

    });




@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 999:
        // set date picker as current date
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
    }
    return null;
}



private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        final Calendar cf = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cf.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = cf.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = cf.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



            // set selected date into textview
            shipdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));
        }


};
```

Comment: I'm new to droid, still reading alot of books. So your going to have to spell out how to use this code because when i paste it into my fragment and import everything it's still bugging out.